# How to create EDIT method and EDIT Razor View for Image which i stored in database in VARBINARY datatype in ASP.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Here is my Create Method

```
  /*  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Image newRecipe)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new  MitishaKitchenContext())
            {
                db.Images.Add(newRecipe);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch { return View(); }
    }*/

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Image IG)
    {
        // Apply Validation Here



        if (IG == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        if (IG != null && IG.File.ContentLength > (2 * 1024 * 1024))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "File size must be less than 2 MB");
            return View();
        }
        if (!(IG.File.ContentType == "image/jpeg" || IG.File.ContentType == "image/gif"))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "File type allowed : jpeg and gif");
            return View();
        } 

      //  IG.FileName = IG.File.FileName;
      //  IG.ImageSize = IG.File.ContentLength;

        byte[] data = new byte[IG.File.ContentLength];
        IG.File.InputStream.Read(data, 0, IG.File.ContentLength);

        IG.ImageData = data;
        using (MitishaKitchenContext dc = new MitishaKitchenContext())
        {
            dc.Images.Add(IG);
            dc.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

}

How  to  create EDIT method and EDIT Razor View for Image which i stored in database in VARBINARY datatype  in ASP.net MVC?

Here is my Create View:

```
{

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Recipes",null,         FormMethod.Post,new   {enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
        {
          @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


         <fieldset>
    <legend>Image</legend>



    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImageName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageName)
    </div>
      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Recipe.RecipeName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Recipe.RecipeName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Recipe.RecipeName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Recipe.RecipeDescriptions)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Recipe.RecipeDescriptions,new {style = "width:90%;height:400px"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Recipe.RecipeDescriptions)

    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Recipe.RecipeIngredients)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Recipe.RecipeIngredients)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Recipe.RecipeIngredients)
    </div>


       <br />
    <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Select File : </td>
                    <td>
                       @Html.TextBoxFor(Model=> Model.File, new{type="file"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table> 
enter code here
             </fieldset>
     }  

}
```

Comment: You want the user to edit an image inside a web page?

Comment: you want to have field to upload the image at the place of the existing one right ?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have the following components in your database table:
RecordId, ImageName, RecipeName, RecipeDescriptions, RecipeDescriptions, ImageData.

Then in the edit you can do something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int recordId)
{
        using (var db = new  MitishaKitchenContext())
        {
            // fetch data for the image by Id
            var yourmodel = db.Images.Where(x => x.RecordId == recordId).FirstOrDefault();

            if(yourmodel != null)
            {
                 return View("Create", yourmodel);
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

You can use the same view as the Create uses as the model will populate your fields. And then you should search if the recordId exists and upsert(insert or update if it already exists).